# Using Wildfly, can I listen remotely for cache events?

Tags: hibernate, wildfly, infinispan

I have Wildfly configured to use caches for hibernate, as shown below:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:3.0">
<cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query" module="org.hibernate.infinispan">
     <local-cache name="local-query">
        <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
        <eviction strategy="LRU" size="10000"/>
        <expiration max-idle="28800000"/>
    </local-cache>
    <local-cache name="entity">
        <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
        <eviction strategy="LRU" size="10000"/>
        <expiration max-idle="28800000"/>
    </local-cache>
    <local-cache name="timestamps">
        <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
        <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
    </local-cache>
</cache-container>
</subsystem>
```

I would like to expose a hotrod endpoint and listen to cache events in a very similar way to how I can do this with Infinispan Server. I am doing this because I am replicating the underlying database manually and selectively, and I would like to manually invalidate the Hibernate cache on the other end as well.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can embed the hotrod server in a WildFly deployment.
You need to grab the WildFly cache manager from JNDI and then launch the HotRodServer with it. I have a little project [1] which demonstrates how to set up something like this.

[1] https://github.com/tristantarrant/infinispan-playground-embedded-hotrod

Comment: Could this be done using configuration in standalone.xml though? I would prefer to just bind it like I can in the Infinispan Server using xml configuration. I am trying the above solution today/tomorrow and will let you know how it goes.

Comment: No. You would need to carry the endpoint subsystem over from Infinispan Server and make it work with the infinispan subsystem in WidlFly.

Comment: So if I carry the endpoint subsystem over, should I expect it to work? I have tried this previously but I believe I may have used the wrong version of some jars.